# Is there a command-line program that can convert an image to an ASCII art image?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing, batch, ascii

Is there a command-line program that can convert an image to ascii art and then save that output as an image e.g. jpg or png?

To illustrate what I'm in need of, I want to convert the image below into ascii art
[image]

The output that I desire from a program should be similar to this one, which was created by taking a screenshot of the output of an image-to-ascii converter (the output was pure text)

[image]

I'm aware that GIMP has the ability to save an image as ascii art and [aview](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aview/) can also convert an image to ascii. However, the former cannot be done via the command line and the latter only lets you view the output, not save it (I don't want to resort to taking a screenshot of the output).

I'm also aware that [libcaca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca) can save its output to an image, but it only outputs colourful ascii, like below.

[image]

Made by converting the source image to greyscale and then with the following command:

```
img2txt -W 70 -f tga input.jpg > output.tga
```

The reason for wanting a command-line program is to batch process a folder full of images.

Comment: Change the image to black and white before using libcaca?

Comment: Everything you can do in GIMP can be done from command line.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov Can you tell me exactly how to accomplish this task?

Comment: No, I can't tell you exactly, because it I only used GIMP's Scheme based scripting a few times and figuring proper API for your question would take just too much time for me right now. I can direct you to relevant docs though: http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-script-fu.html.

Comment: @Bert I tried using a greyscale and black/white image. It occasional still renders to a colourful output and still uses coloured/shaded tiles as a background. I want it in pure ascii, which just uses b/w text

Comment: Related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18352/is-there-a-command-line-program-that-can-output-ascii-art-as-an-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say you don't want to resort to taking a screenshot, do you mean that you don't want to have to resort to taking a screenshot manually?  Generating images with `aview` and taking screenshots of the results could be automated.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

aview $1 &
pid=$!
sleep 1 # Give aview time to map its window.
xwd -name "aa for X" | convert - $2
kill $pid
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not an answer to the final question, but a hint, if you just read the title: Why use ascii? If you just search for a way to get a hint of images on the console, better use a terminal with Sixel support and show images directly in the terminal:

```
apt install libsixel-bin mlterm
mlterm
img2sixel test.jpg
```

works on Ubuntu 19.10!

[image]

Comment: You've completely missed the point of the question. The goal is not just to display the image in a terminal. ascii is the desired output.

Comment: I was ending up here at this question when I was searching for a way to watch images on the console and thought ASCII would be the solution. Your question title sounds like that. So after some more research I found out that there is an even better solution for my problem. I thought it would be nice to share it with you, just in case